# Proof that infinitely many $f$ exist if $f(f(x))=f(x)^{2013}$

Tags: analysis, contest-math

> Suppose $f(x)$ is function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x))=f(x)^{2013}$. Show that there are infinitely many such functions, of which exactly four are polynomials.

If $f$ is constant ($f(x) = c$), the value of $c$ satisfying $f(f(x)) = f(x)^{2013}$ would be $-1$, $0$ and $1$.

For non-constant $f$, the polynomial $g(x)=f(x)-x^{2013}$ would have all elements of the range of $f$ ($\{f(x)\mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$) as its roots. Since $f(x)$ is everywhere continuous, $g$ has infinitely many roots, making it the zero polynomial. Thus $f(x)=x^{2013}$ for all real values of $x$.  This proves the existence of the four polynomials.

Now, how would I prove the existence of infinitely many $f$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To every $x$ you can assign $-1$, $0$, or $1$. There are infinitely many ways of doing this. As Hagen notes,  the only restriction is that you need $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(-1)=-1$.

Comment: playing on the fact that $f$ need not be continuous?

Comment: All you need to take care is that $f(x)=x$ for $x\in\{-1,0,1\}$

Comment: @ellya: of course; the OP has already shown that when $f$ is continuous it is one of the 4 polynomials.

Comment: @Hagen: thanks, I have added that to the answer.