# $f(f(x))=f(x)^{2013}$ continued…

Tags: functions, contest-math

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775328/proof-that-infinitely-many-f-exist-if-ffx-fx2013) was a question that appeared in CMI BSc (Hons) Mathematics exam. It asks about finding a real function $f(x)$ such that $$f(f(x))=f(x)^{2013}$$

Along with the answer already given in the question linked to above, I found another function, namely: $$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 x^{2013}&\text{if}\, 0\leq x\leq 1\\
      0.5&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Instead of 0.5 we can choose any value in $[0,1]$

Now my question is: **What other functions also satisfy the same property?**

I am looking for other ways to approach this problem in order to gain intuition at solving similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be any set such that $x^{2013} \in A$ whenever $x \in A$. Examples are $[0,1], [0,\infty), [1,\infty) $etc. Let $f(x)=x^{2013}$ for $x \in A$ and let $f$ map elements of $A^{c}$ in any manner into the set $A$. Then $f$ is a solution of the given equation. Also, any solution is of this type (where $A$ is the range of $f$).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how ‘any solution is of this type’?

Comment: Once you define $A$ as the range of $f$ it follows immediately from the given equation that $f$ has the form I have described. Nothing to prove here. @SohamSaha

Comment: And the other elements of $A^c$ have to get mapped to something in $A$ so that new elements don’t get added to the range right? I think I have got it now…

Comment: Everything is maped into the range $A$, so elements of $A^{c}$ are also mapped into $A$. @SohamSaha

Comment: Agreed. Got it now, this was exactly the kind of intuition I was looking for.